# What is the maximum size of a struct?

Tags: struct

Assuming gas and hard drive space are not an issue, if you had a struct containing arrays how much data could you actually put into those arrays before the struct reaches its maximum size?  I am attempting to use mapping to a struct to keep track of some information and would like to understand how much I can give it before it cannot get any larger and what I can do to help keep the data record past that.

My current plan is to create a new struct that references the previous maps key once the struct is at its max size, but I don't know if that is an ideal situation yet.

Comment: You do realize that the struct is just a compilation symbol that helps with encapsulation, right? The amount of data that you can store in a mapping is independent of whether or not you declare that mapping inside a struct. Same goes for an array.

Comment: The only issue that you may have with the size of a struct is that if you declare in it more than 16 slots (or something like that), then you won't be able to instantiate it as a local variable in a function because it will exceed the maximum stack size.

Comment: I did not realize that struct sizes were inconsequential (other than a too many variables issue), I didn't think the mapping part would effect anything but I wanted to be clear, thank you @goodvibration, I thought it would in the very least be limited by the smart contract it was on but finding that it could have as much data as the host can hold is great.